# Dynamically update Menu in SideBar

Tags: reactjs

I have a sideBar component which accpets, Menu items to display.

but the menu items keep changing based on the current rendered page. How do I update the menu item from child components.

**app.js**

content

```
const items = [
    { path: '/home', label: 'Home' },
    { path: '/about', label: 'About' },
]
<Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={3} id="sidebar-wrapper">      
                  <Sidebar items={items}/>
                </Col>
                <Col  xs={9} id="page-content-wrapper">
                <Routes />
                </Col> 
            </Row>

  </Container>
```

Sidebar.js

return (

```
        <Nav className="col-md-12 d-none d-md-block sidebar">
        {items.map(({ label, name, ...rest }) => (
            <Nav.Item key={name} button {...rest}>
            <Nav.Link href={name}>{label}</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
        ))}
        
        </Nav>

   
    );
```

Now when the page is scrolled to /about the items will be

```
const items = [
    { path: '/contact us', label: 'contact' },
    { path: '/address', label: 'address' },
    { path: '/item 3', label: 'item 3' },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Integrate `redux` in your app for the state management.
2. Create a seperate store variable `sideBarItems` in the store and update it on the basis of `path`.
3. In your component `Sidebar.js`, map the `sidebarItems`, everytime this variable is updated in the store, new sidebar items will be rendered.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. I thought for smaller app like mine, I won't need redux. but I guess its time to learn redux too.